# Bootstrap: Social Media Buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I am trying to show social media buttons in my footer. This is the `<ul>`:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
<li><a href="#" class="icoRss" title="Rss"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icoGoogle" title="Google +"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="icoLinkedin" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

I have included this refrences as well:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

But it isn't working, Anyhelp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

before // put http: working fine

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Yout font awesome link do not exist):

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/L1ec56b5/)**

> If does not work you have a problem  has been blocked from loading by
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.

Add this to your `.htaccess` file.

```
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: tried this one too, it isn't working with this reference as well.

Comment: Maybe is a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy  problem. I edit my answer

Comment: I have downloaded the `font-awesome.min.css` file, now accessing it from my own computer, still not working.

Comment: Did you put my code on your `.htaccess` file like i said?

Comment: Where to find this file, I don't have this file.

Comment: Are you running APACHE web server? If so, create a file in your text editor and save it as `.htaccess` on your project root - http://htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: No, I m not using apache, I am working on front end design for now, in a `.html` file.